# How to initialize an empty object with ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, initialization, attributeerror, nonetype

My models.py looks like that :

```
class B(models.Model):
    ...

class C(models.Model):
    ...

class D(models.Model):
    ...

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, blank=True, null=True)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, blank=True,null=True)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D, blank=True,null=True)
```

In views.py, I have to initialize an empty A, and fill it later. I can use

```
i = A().save()
```

But when I try something like :

```
i.b.add(objectb)
```

This exception occurs :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'b'
```

I tried to cancel the null=True :

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, blank=True)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, blank=True)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D, blank=True)
```

But then another exception occured :

```
A.b_id may not be NULL
```

I can't figure out how to initialize an empty but not "None" A.

I need your help,

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) and [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

To initialize a Foreign key, you would just do:

```
i = A().save()
i.b = objectb
i.save()
```

where `objectb` is an instance of class `B`

The reason `i.b.add(objectb)` throws an exception is,

`i.b` is accessing the attribute `b` of the model instance `i`, which is `None`, and when the ORM tries to call the `add` on `b`, it is indeed `None`. Hence the error.

Comment: in fact, my A object can have multiple B objects, but a B is related to only one A. It's like a OneToMany relationship, that's why I use ForeignKey. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes. In that case, your foreign key is on the wrong model. Because, You cannot assign multiple `b` to and `a`. If you put the foreign key on `b`, you can do stuff like `a.b_set.all()` to give all the `b` associated with `a`.

Comment: revisit your implementation. `A` would atleast have something like a `name`. If there are _no_ attributes, why would you event want that model ??

Comment: Another way to look at it could be: add a unique constraint on `(b, c, d)` in class `A`

Comment: I could do without A, but I "need" it for my database to be "real". Actually, your first commentary helped me a lot, and I will keep in mind the constraint

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = A()
b = B()
b.save()
a.b = b
a.save()
```

Comment: You have to call `save` after assigning the foreign key.

Comment: Just an optimization. You dont need `a.save()` twice. Sorry. I dont mean to be a snob :P

Comment: I was just realizing that. I'm going to edit it out. :]

Comment: Actually, I don't want to set b as the value of a.b, I just want to add b to the a.b "list". I mean a possesses multiple b.

Comment: Then the fk relationship is backwards, I think. If B belongs to A, the B should have the fk to A.